# I'm trying to turn selection into function in Toad/Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, stored-functions

I'm trying turn this selection into function. 
Instead of sysdate user will give his own date that he wanted to see.
(Sorry for bad english).

```
SELECT  trunc(sysdate),
        trunc(sysdate) - 1,
        trunc(sysdate) - 2,
        trunc(sysdate) - 3,
        trunc(last_day(sysdate)-1, 'mm'),       
        add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -1) first_day_of_last_month,
        add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -2) first_day_of_last_month,
        add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -3) first_day_of_last_month,
        add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'Q'), -6) first_day_of_last_quarter,
        add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'Q'), -9) first_day_of_last_quarter,
        add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'Q'), -12) first_day_of_last_quarter,
        add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'Q'), -15) first_day_of_last_quarter,
        add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'Q'), -18) first_day_of_last_quarter
FROM dual;
```

Result should be looking like this in 1 Row

```
1/7/2019    1/6/2019    1/5/2019    1/4/2019    1/1/2019    12/1/2018   11/1/2018   10/1/2018   7/1/2018    4/1/2018    1/1/2018    10/1/2017   7/1/2017
```

Comment: Just go ahead and turn it into a function, what's stopping you?

Comment: What would you be looking to return from the function? Do you want to return a cursor? Do you want it to return as a pipelined table function? More details are needed before we can make any specific suggestions.

Comment: My main issue is i don't know how to return multiple values in function and instead of sysdate user will give his own date and function should return 1 row with multiple values.

Comment: Why `trunc(last_day(pdt_ref_date)-1, 'mm')`? That will always be the same as `trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'mm')`

Comment: @Boneist Well i'm newbie and i didn't know. Thank you for your response

Comment: Hopefully you understand why they're the same? (Finding the last day of the month for the date variable and then subtracting 1 from it means that the resultant date will always have the same month as the original date variable.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a function returning a ref cursor.

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_dates(pdt_ref_date IN DATE)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
    pcr_result SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN pcr_result FOR
    SELECT  
        trunc(pdt_ref_date),
        trunc(pdt_ref_date) - 1,
        trunc(pdt_ref_date) - 2,
        trunc(pdt_ref_date) - 3,
        trunc(last_day(pdt_ref_date)-1, 'mm'),       
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'MM'), -1) first_day_of_last_month,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'MM'), -2) first_day_of_last_month,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'MM'), -3) first_day_of_last_month,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'Q'), -6) first_day_of_last_quarter,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'Q'), -9) first_day_of_last_quarter,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'Q'), -12) first_day_of_last_quarter,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'Q'), -15) first_day_of_last_quarter,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'Q'), -18) first_day_of_last_quarter
    FROM dual;

    RETURN pcr_result;
END;
```

Which can be used the following way:

```
SELECT get_dates(SYSDATE)
FROM DUAL;
```

Note that:

- I don't know the purpose of this function so I generically called it
  `get_dates`
- You may need to define this function in a package,
  especially if you have several related functions/procs

Comment: Thank you for the response. The purpose of this function is for daily, monthly, quarter financial reports. User will give his dates and report's date will show up. Currently i'm using Toad and "invalid SQL statement" this error is showing how can i fix this.